# How to send Json object (or string data) from Javascript xmlhttprequest to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I created a web application in ASP.NET MVC and trying to call a controller through Javascript AJAX. In Jquery we can send a json object which MVC Model Binder automatically tries to create a .NET object and pass in the controller as an argument.

However I am using a web workers in which jquery cannot be used. So I am making the AJAX call through the vanilla xmlhttprequest object. Is there a a way to send the Json object through this method?

I used the xmlhttprequest's send method but the model object comes as null in the controller :(

Comment: Good use of the word vanilla :) I like that

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should just be able to use JSON2 to stringify it and set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` when you do the post.

http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js

You would do something like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/Controller/Action');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(myData));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dve!! It is working on the main thread. Now I am going to try on the worker thread.  Will post the results

Comment: It is working on the worker thread too!! Awesome, thanks Darin and Dve.

Comment: var myData = {}; myData.Name = 'XXX';

Comment: This works in ASP.NET MVC but not in ASP.NET Core MVC application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example. It assumes that you are using ASP.NET MVC 3.0 which has a built-in `JsonValueProviderFactory`. If this is not your case you could take a look at [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx).

View model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
    {
        return Content("success", "text/plain");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var value = '{ "prop1": "value 1", "prop2": "value 2" }';
    // It would be better to use JSON.stringify to properly generate
    // a JSON string
    /**
    var value = JSON.stringify({
        prop1: 'value 1',
        prop2: 'value 2'
    });
    **/

    http.open('POST', '/Home/SomeAction', true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', value.length);
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(value); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Darin - I tried exact same method as you told and also registered the JSonValueProviderFactory in Global.asax. however the model object still has null properties. I used same property names in JSon object as well but its not able to bind it to a json object. Also I found this error in Firefox - not sure if its relavent Error: uncaught exception:  [nsIXMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:6438/Scripts/script.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 40"  data: no]

Answer (score -1):

Using $.Ajax(), you can easily got the data from javascript to Controller in MVC.

For Reference,

> `var uname = 'Nikhil Prajapati';`
>   `$.ajax({`
>
> ```
>       url: "/Main/getRequestID",  // This is path of your Controller with Action Result.
>       dataType: "json",           // Data Type for sending the data
>
>       data: {                     // Data that will be passed to Controller
>           'my_name': uname,     // assign data like key-value pair       
>            // 'my_name'  like fields in quote is same with parameter in action Result
>       },
>
>       type: "POST",               // Type of Request
>       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //Optional to specify Content Type.
>
>       success: function (data) { // This function is executed when this request is succeed.
>               alert(data);
>       },
>
>       error: function (data) {
>               alert("Error");   // This function is executed when error occurred.
>       }
> ```
>
> )};

and, Now At the Controller Side,

> public ActionResult getRequestID(String my_name)
>      {
>
> ```
>         MYDBModel myTable = new Models.MYDBModel();
>         myTable.FBUserName = my_name;
>         db.MYDBModel.Add(myTable);
>         db.SaveChanges();              // db object of our DbContext.cs
>         //return RedirectToAction(“Index”);   // After that you can redirect to some pages…
>         return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);    // Or you can get that data back after inserting into database.. This json displays all the details to our view as well.
>     }
> ```

For more reference..
just visit..
[Send Data from Java Script to Controller in MVC](http://dotnetternikhil.blogspot.in/2014/12/send-data-from-java-script-to.html)